# How can VLC be stopped from opening two windows for each video opened?

Tags: 18.04, vlc

When I highlight multiple video files within Nautilus, right-click on them and open them with VLC, VLC proceeds to open *two* windows for each video, with one window featuring just the video and the other window featuring just the VLC controls.

[image]

This is a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation running the MATE desktop environment and the VLC settings "Allow only one instance", "One instance when started from file" and ""Integrate video in interface"" all are switched on. How might this two-window VLC behaviour be stopped?

The behaviour seems to be similar to that described [here](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?317063-VLC-opens-two-windows-when-started-from-Nautilus-with-several-file-handles).

Comment: I know this is old but did you ever find a solution to this. I'm on Ubuntu 21.10 and still have this issue. I've tried all sorts of settings but gave up and used another application but would really like to use VLC. The one answer below did not work.

Comment: I'm afraid I never did get an explanation for the behaviour. In case it helps, I do not currently observe the behaviour on my Ubuntu 20.04 system with VLC 3.0.9.2, and for the time that I stopped using VLC I used [MPV](https://mpv.io) for videos and I used [Audacious](https://audacious-media-player.org) for music.

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you. For me it is hit and miss. Sometimes opens in one window and sometimes two. I have an nvidia graphics card and read somewhere that setting the video output to VDPAU fixes this issue. It kind of did, but not always. I'm using 3.0.17 with Ubuntu 21.10. It's so annoying. I might try MPV, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

Tools => Preferences => Video => select full screen in display settings. That should fix it. Worked for me. Also in preferences => interface => tick both allow only one instance and use only one instance when started from file manager in playlist and instances